Trying to get data from a website with locator and captcha
I am trying to gather data from this website: https://locator.infusioncenter.org/ for a personal project of mine.
I would like to gather a file containing all the locations that show up on the locator. However, you are limited to a 100 mile radius. Would there be anyway to get past this radius on the website, or would you guys recommend trying to scrape it using Python?
I haven't tried much, I'm not to experienced with using Python for webscraping, so I was kind of stuck behind the captcha that comes with the website.

I'm not sure if it's possible to effectively bypass captcha automatically (actually, that's a good news for all of us :) ). But if it's a one-off thing for you, you can open jupyter notebook and run your script from there. You will be able to keep website open by selenium driver and at the same time interacting with it manually. So once, you opened the website, complete the captcha manually, then go back to your notebook and collect the data you need.
Please, be responsible with workload you generate on the website and the usage of data you collected this way.

Hey thanks so much for your response! I tried doing that, but the captcha wheel just spun for like 10 minutes without much happening. Not sure what is causing that, would love to know if you have any advice.

Interesting, not really. Probably worth trying changing the user-agent of the selenium driver.
